# Test a block that has no action and receives a notification?

Tags: chef-infra, chefspec

So, I am trying to add some unit test to my recipe.

Testing something that has an action is easy.
But when your action is :nothing because it gets triggered by a notification then it sucks.
The following block gets called with: 
notifies :create, 'directory[Create my directory]', :immediately

```
directory 'Create my directory' do
  path myPath
  mode '0755'
  owner 'me'
  group 'aGroup'
  action :nothing
  notifies :create_if_missing, 'remote_file[Download artifact]', :immediately
  notifies :run, 'execute[unpack artifact]', :immediately
end
```

When before the action was :create the unit test was simple

```
it 'Test create directory' do
    expect(chef_run).to create_directory('Create my directory')
        .with_path('myPath')
        .with_mode('0755')
        .with_owner('me')
        .with_group('aGroup')  
end
```

so how do you test something when it receives a notification?

Answer (score -1):

Comment the `action :nothing`, make a kitchen test run and see the results. Do not forget to un-comment the line after testing.